# La nuanco inter du malsametaj “ni”

Tags: single-word-requests, word-formation

En ĉina mandarino estas du vortoj por "ni"

- Women / 我们 
  Ni, sed la aŭskultanto ne estas inklusivita. Do Women nur reprezentas la diranton.
- Zanmen／咱们
  Ni, inklusive la aŭskultanto. Do Zamen inklusivas ambaŭ la diranton kaj la aŭskultantojn.

Tiuj nuancaj vortoj fakte estas tre utilaj en iuj kazoj. Eĉ, en iuj specialaj kazoj la du vortoj kaŭzas tute malsamajn signifojn:

Ekzemple:

Rang Women Yiqiqu (让我们一起去) / Ni iru kune: Vi petas la aŭkultanton lasi vin iri kun viaj amikoj.

Rang Zamen Yiqiqu（让咱们一起去）/ Ni iru kune: Vi sugestas al la aŭskultanto iri kune kun vi.

En Esperanto ĉu ni povas krei tian vorton/ esprimon? Se jes, mi ŝatus scii viajn proponojn. Dankon.

Comment: La titolo de la demando kaj la unua frazo estas en la angla, la cetero — en Esperanto. Bonvolu redakti ĝin, tiel ke ĉio estas en unu lingvo.

Comment: Bona sugesto, dankon, @Lyubomir

Comment: Estas ankaŭ du nuancoj por ‘kompreni’: “wo bu ming bai” kaj “wo ting bu dong” – tre utila distingo kiu ne ekzistas en la angla kaj nek en Esperanto.

Comment: Lauxvorte: 1) “Wo bu mingbai/ 我不明白”= mi ne klarigxas. 2) “Wo ting bu dong/我听不懂”= mi ne auxskulte komprenas. La nuancoj estas: 1) Mi komprenas viajn frazojn vorton-apud-vorto sed mi ankoraux ne komprenas la signifon de viaj frazoj. 2) Mi ne povas scipovi kion vi diras. Dankon pro via mencio pri tio cxar kiel denaskulo de cxinlingvo mi tute ne imagis tion kio kauxzas al alilingvuloj malfacilon.

Comment: Nu, bone, sed vi povus koncize priskribi la du sencojn per topologia analogio: Senco #1 diras, “Niaj fermaĵoj interkruciĝas, sed niaj internoj ne interkruciĝas.” Senco #2 diras, “Niaj fermaĵoj ne interkruciĝas.” --> http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/vorto-understand.html

Answer (score 6):

En Esperanto, "ni" povas signifi unu el du aferoj:

- Mi, vi, kaj iuj aliaj personoj.
- Mi kun iuj aliaj personoj, sed ne vi.

Se estas ŝanco de miskompreno, oni trovu alian manieron klarigi.

- Vi kaj mi iros al la trajno. Panjo restos hejme.
- Ni, tio estas mi kaj miaj kolegoj, faros la laboron.

Comment: Jes, Tiaj vortoj ankaux mankas en aliaj cxinaj dialektoj.  Ekzemple en mia dialekto (sudokcidenta mandarino) mi ja tiele esprimas por distingi la malsamajn kazojn. ankoraux mi klopodas trovi simplan kaj elegantan solvon. :)

Answer (score 3):

Malkiel la Ĉina (kaj multaj Pacifikaj lingvoj) Esperanto ne distingas inter inkluda kaj malinkluda *ni*. Oni devus reformi la lingvon. :-) Mi vidis reformproponon ”iŝi” por plurala ”ŝi” (similie al ”li” > ”ili”). Do eble en iu reformita Esperanto oni povus distingi inter ”imi” (”mi kaj mi, sed ne vi”) kaj ”ni” (”mi kaj mi kaj vi”). Atentu tamen ke ne simplas ŝanĝi pronomojn! La riistoj dum multaj jaroj klopodis anstataŭi je ”li” kaj ”ŝi” per sekse neŭtrala ”ri” – sed la plimulto de la Esperantolingvanoj ankoraŭ diradas ”li” kaj ”ŝi”. :-)

Comment: dankon pro la interesaj informoj :) @Bjøm

Comment: Oni respondu pri Esperanto, ne pri reformoj.

Comment: Krome, nur en norda mandarino estas tiaj vortoj- ili ankaux mankas en aliaj dialektoj.  Ekzemple en mia dialekto (sudokcidenta mandarino) mi ankoraux klopodas trovi simplan kaj elegantan solvon.

Comment: @Tomaso Alexander – Jes, mi konsentas pri tio. La unua frazo sufiĉus kiel respondo. Tamen notu la demandon: *En Esperanto ĉu ni povas **krei** tian vorton/ esprimon?* Do, mi esence diras ke *ne*, en Esperanto kia ĝi estas, oni *ne* povas krei tian vorton – oni tiucele devus reformi la lingvon. Laŭ mi, estu loko por iomete da fantaziumado. Mi certe ne subtenas tian reformon! :-)