# How do you say “mondegreen” in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word “[mondegreen](http://enciklopedia-vortaro-de-la-merk-angla.weebly.com/vorto-mondegreen.html)” appears neither in Benson, nor in Wells, nor in Vikivortaro, nor in ReVo. How would you render it in Esperanto?

Comment: Via ligilo proponas la vorton ”misaŭdaĵo”. Ĉu ne sufiĉe bona? :-)

Comment: @Bjørn: Eble, sed mi estas fiŝkaptanta por pli bona termino. Ĉu, ekzemple, ‘mondegrenaĵo’ estus tro terura neologismo?

Comment: Nu, neologismojn utilajn kaj klarajn mi ne kontraŭas, sed mi demandas min ĉu ’mondegrenaĵo’ estus tia? Ĝi estas pli longa ol ’misaŭdaĵo’; ĝi aspektas kunmetita de jamaj esperantovortoj (mon-de-gren-); finfine, mi ne scias ĉu ĝi vere internacias, aŭ ĉu nur konatas en la Angla… (Mi ekzemple unuafoje renkontis la esperimon ĉí tie. :-)  )

Answer (score 4):

> Mondegreen - a misunderstood or misinterpreted word or phrase resulting from a mishearing of the lyrics of a song. - Google

Misaŭdaĵo = a thing that is misheard

Answer (score 2):

In my native language, Danish, there is no one word for it either, and native speakers just call it “misforståede sangtekster” which translates to “misunderstood song lyrics”. Thus I'd just translate it to “miskomprenitaj kantotekstoj”.

There's no reason to overcomplicate a translation by inventing a new word. When translating, the goal is to translate the meaning, not the words.

Comment: This expression is not only too long, and not only is unnecessarily restrictive to songs, but also suffers from the fact that there is more than one sense of (mis)understand, as I note in a comment in this question: http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2716/la-nuanco-inter-du-malsametaj-ni#comment2796_2716

Answer (score 1):

**misvortigaĵo** comes to mind: that the words were constructed wrong. Not very convincing. I like **fuŝaŭdo**, which seems better than **mis~**.